# How to create tar file with 7zip

Tags: tar, 7zip

I'm trying to create a tar file on windows using 7zip.

Most of the documents I found said to do something like this:

```
7z a -ttar -so dwt.tar dwt/
```

But when I tried to run it I got this error:

> Command Line Error: 
>   I won't write compressed data to a terminal

I'm currently using 7-Zip [64] 16.04

Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

On Linux:

```
tar cf - <source folder> | 7z a -si <Destination archive>.tar.7z
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300097/how-do-i-create-tar-7z-file-from-the-command-line)

On Windows:

```
7za.exe a -ttar -so archive.tar source_files | 7za.exe a -si archive.tgz
```

from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/339931/how-do-i-use-7-zip-cli-for-windows-to-create-tar-gz-archives#339964).

Comment: I'm currently doing that, but I'm keep getting the error.
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -ttar -so test.tar test"

Comment: You are not using the command suggested in my answer. You are using the one in your question. Look carefully, there is a pipe followed by another 7z command. -so writes to stdout, that's why it keeps giving you the error.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to do that making simply, with 7zip installed:

- Right click on the folder you want to compress
- Choose -7zip/add to file
- Once there, on the new screen, on file type, you can choose 7z/tar/wim/zip
- Choose tar, and there you go :)

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage:

```
   -so    Write data to stdout (e.g. 7z x -so directory.tar.7z | tar xf -)
```

It does what you told it to. 7z can guess archive format from the file extension so it's enough to use

```
7z a archive.tar input/
```

To further compress as gzip you can use a pipe and a combination of stdin and stdout flags like in Tu.Ma.'s answer.